# Cannot find drl resource in ejb project

Tags: java, glassfish, optaplanner

I am creating an enterprise application (Glassfish 4) which uses optaplanner (6.0.1). The solver is launched from within the EJB project. I can load the xml configuration just find, but it wont find the drl building the solver.

```
SolverFactory solverFactory = new XmlSolverFactory().configure(PropositionSB.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/todoSolverConfig.xml"));
Solver solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
```

Throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scoreDrl (/resources/todoScoreRules.drl) does not exist as a classpath resource.
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildKieBase(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:304)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:279)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:186)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:174)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:145)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory.buildSolver(XmlSolverFactory.java:101)
at entityManagement.PropositionSB.solve(PropositionSB.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 53 more
```

I dont have this same problem when working on simple Java Application though.

Comment: What's your app server? Glassfish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following on your app server:

```
// OptaPlanner 6.0
URL r = SolverFactory.class.getResource("/resources/todoScoreRules.drl"); 
System.out.println("Resource found: " + (r == null));

// OptaPlanner 6.1+
URL r = SolverFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/todoScoreRules.drl"); 
System.out.println("Resource found: " + (r == null));
```

Then try replacing `SolverFactory.class` with your own `getClass()`.

Also, [the docs added in this pull request](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/pull/52) might be related.

Comment: I can find the resource when using my own class but not with SolverFactory.
    SolverFactory.class.getResource("");
return the path to the jar in the deployed application.
I managed to get this to work by copying the optaplanner sources directly in my project.

Comment: In that case, it's better to use `SolverFactory.createFromXmlInputStream(r.getInputStream())` (requires OptaPlanner 6.1, use 6.1.0.CR2 or Final which will be released in the next few days)